# Login PHP caso seja Admin

Tags: php, login

Boas,

tenho uma duvida no codigo que estou a fazer. 
Quero que os utilizadores normais vejam uma pagina mas caso seja o login admin vá parar a outra página .

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT Nome, Password FROM tb_utilizador WHERE Nome = '$Nome' AND Password = '$Password'");
$loginadm = mysql_query("SELECT Nome, Password FROM tb_utilizador WHERE Nome = 'ADMIN' AND Password = 'AdminAdmin'");
$res = mysql_fetch_row($login);
$resadm = mysql_fetch_row($login);
if($res)
    {
        header('location:compras.html');
    }
    else 
    {
         echo "<p>Utilizador ou password invalidos. <a href=\"index.html\">Tente novamente</a></p>";
    }
if($resadm)
    {
        header('location:comprasADM.html');
    }
    else if ($loginAdm)
    {
         echo "<p>Utilizador ou password invalidos. <a href=\"index.html\">Tente novamente</a></p>";
    }
```

Comment: `$resadm = mysql_fetch_row($login);` isto não devia ser `$resadm = mysql_fetch_row($loginadm);` ?

Comment: Desculpem o meu Português.
Tu devias estar ciente de que a função`mysql_*` é obsoleta. Y ja ja não se usa em PHP7 .. Devias estar usando as funções `mysqli_*` ou PDO (PHP Data Objects).

Answer (score 1):

O melhor para isso é acrescentar ou uma tabela de admins (seria o que eu faria) ou acrecentar uma coluna em `tb_utilizador` com o nome por ex: `is_admin`, que pode assumir dois valores para cada linha, "1" (é admin), ou "0" (não é admin). Vou fazer de acordo com esta ultima opção:

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT Nome, Password, is_admin FROM tb_utilizador WHERE Nome = '$Nome' AND Password = '$Password'");
$res = mysql_fetch_row($login);

if($res) {
     if($res[2] == 1) {
         header('location:comprasADM.html');
     }
     header('location:compras.html');
}
// isto não vai acontecer se formos redirecionados antes, se estiver tudo bem com qualquer dos logins
echo "<p>Utilizador ou password invalidos. <a ...
```

Nota que não vale a pena estarmos a fazer duas requesições à base de dados.

Comment: Embora teoricamente a sua resposta esteja correta, vamos supor que existe mais que um administrador, você irá estar constantemente a usar querys ? O seu exemplo está correto, mas penso que pode apenas fazer com o "is_admin" . 'ADMIN' e 'AdminAdmin' pode não ser o unico acesso de administrador. Se o is_admin corresponder a 1 então ele vai ver a outra página exclusiva a ele, não precisa de acrescentar o utilizador e a password, podemos fazer com esse unico campo

Comment: Você pode fazer isso reduzindo a sua query e utilizando apenas "is_admin" , você a partir desse unico campo consegue saber se é admin ou nao ( 1 ou 0 )

Comment: Em casos de sistemas desenvolvidos, e aqueles mais "pesados", reduzir a query a apenas um campo tem como vantagem tornar o sistema mais fléxivel e a consulta à base de dados mais eficiente. Nós a partir do "is_admin" apenas, conseguimos saber se é administrador ou um usuário. Claro que pode!

Comment: Obrgado @FábioArsénio

Comment: Cara, eu tenho uma pergunta bem parecida que não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum, se puderem dar uma olhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241731/login-com-sistema-de-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o/242040#242040