# Login com sistema de validação

Tags: php, mysql, login

No login do meu sistema, se o usuário tiver id e senha cadastrados o acesso é liberado. Até aí tudo bem, mas agora quero qualificar esse usuário em administrador(1) ou simples usuário(0) para, quando eles logarem, forem redirecionados pra páginas diferentes.

Pra isso, criei um coluna `"ativo"` para armazenar os 0 ou 1 na minha tabela de usuários e comecei a escrever uma página de validação que ainda não está funcionando:

```
<?php

// Primeiro verifica se o post não está vazio
if (!empty($_POST) AND !empty($_POST['identifiant']) OR !empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
    // Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
    $identifiant = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['identifiant']);
    $senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);
    $ativo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ativo']);

    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `identifiant`, `senha`, `ativo`  FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`identifiant` = '". $identifiant ."') AND (`senha` = '". $senha ."')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
      // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
      echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
    } else {
      $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
      // Verifica se o usuário é 0 ou 1

      if ($resultado['ativo'] == 0)) { header("Location: principalUSU.php"); } 
      else { header("Location: principal.php"); }

      exit;
    }
}
?>
```

A página de login é onde está o formulário responsável pelo login e o action que liga com a página de validação:

```
<!--CONTENT-->
    <!--A parte do formulário-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" style="
    margin-top: 14px;">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Login</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="background: rgba(32, 40, 76, 0.59);">
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($erro)) 
                            if(count($erro) > 0){ ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <?php foreach($erro as $msg) echo "$msg <br>"; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php 
                            }
                            ?>
                        <form method="post" action="validacao.php" role="form">
                            <fieldset style="background: #9498a9;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" name="identifiant">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" required placeholder="Senha" name="senha" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Lembrar-me
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" name="login" value="true" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="background: #232b4f; border-color: #e2e2e2;">Login</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

A tabela como no banco de dados:

```
id  |  nome  |  senha  |  ativo  
 1     aaaa     12345       1
 2     bbbb     12345       0
```

Mas quando vou tentar rodar a página, aparece aquele `erro 500` dizendo que a página não está funcionando. 
Alguma ideia do por que não funciona?

*obs: Alterei meu código pra o que aparece aqui na resposta, mas ainda está dando o erro 500.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc ta com problema no primeiro if / else, onde tenta encontrar o tipo de variavel ativo antes de fazer a consulta SQL, a linha abaixo está errada:

```
(`ativo` = 1)
```

Não é uma variável e tbm não se usa esse tipo de acento fora da consulta mysql.

Você tem q fazer a consulta no banco de dados primeiro para depois identificar o tipo de usuário e ai sim abrir a pagina de acordo.

algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

// Primeiro verifica se o post não está vazio, coloque um sinal ! de negação para verificar se identifiant ou senha também não estão vazios.
if (!empty($_POST) AND !empty($_POST['identifiant']) OR !empty($_POST['senha'])) {
  // Caso esteja preenchidos, vamos seguir com o codigo abaixo
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
    // Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
    $identifiant = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['identifiant']);
    $senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);
    $ativo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ativo']);

    // Na linha abaixo não coloque o (`ativo` = '". $ativo ."'), pq é essa informação que vc quer retornar para verificar o tipo de usuário.
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `identifiant`, `senha`, `ativo`  FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`identifiant` = '". $identifiant ."') AND (`senha` = '". $senha ."')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
      // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
      echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
    } else {
      $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
      // Agora sim, vc tem o resultado do banco de dados, é aqui q vc vai verificar se o seu usuário é ativo 0 ou 1;

      if ($resultado['ativo'] == 0)) { header("Location: principalUSU.php"); } 
      else { header("Location: principal.php"); }

      exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Agora só duas dicas...

1) Procure aprender sobre MySQLi, pq os codígos MySQL são antigos, e muitos servidores não utilizam mais.

2) Se o seu sistema conter informações muito confidenciais, sugiro que tente pesquisar melhor sobre segurança para login, pq esse seu método está muito simples, e fácil de ser hackeado.

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços

Comment: Ah, ótima explicação, faz muito mais sentido agora, obrigada pelas dicas; Tentei usar seu código agora mas ainda dá o erro 500. Sabe se pode ser na outra página ou no banco de dados? (vou até editar minha pergunta e colocar seu código)

Comment: Olá Mariana. Tente trocar o mysql por mysqi conforme Fernando mencionou, pois como muitos servidores não utilizam mais, isso pode estar gerando conflitos.

Comment: Apenas para tentar ajudar um pouco. http://phpcodechecker.com
Ajuda a identificar parenteses errados e erros de sintaxe. Cole seus códigos php lá e mande verificar que mostra uma lista com avisos e erros.

Comment: Nossa, isso foi muito útil, hoje mesmo eu estava pensando se existia algo assim

Comment: deve estar dando erro 500 por conta de um erro no código, pelo q vi por cima essa linha `if ($resultado['ativo'] == 0)) { header...` está com um parentese a mais, eu não tinha testado seu código, apenas respondi lendo o q está escrito, mas tenta corrigir essa parte tirando um dos parenteses, ficando assim: `if ($resultado['ativo'] == 0) { header...`. Creio q seja isso.

Comment: A sugestão da resposta do Fox.11 convertendo para mysqli pode te ajudar bastante. Porém sugiro vc dar uma lida na documentação do php para entender melhor como funciona e saber o q está fazendo com seu código. Evite só copiar e colar, assim vc vai ter mais dificuldades de aprender.

Comment: Funcionou, Fernando! Era o parêntese, estou envergonhada. kkkkk Muito obrigada mesmo.

Comment: kkkk q bom q funcionou @MarianaFerreira, não se envergonhe, isso acontece com todo mundo com mais frequência do q vc imagina kkkk abraços.

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim:

```
<?php

// Primeiro verifica se o post não está vazio
if (!empty($_POST) AND !empty($_POST['identifiant']) OR !empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    $conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conexao));
    // Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
    $identifiant = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['identifiant']);
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['senha']);
    $ativo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['ativo']);

    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `identifiant`, `senha`, `ativo`  FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`identifiant` = '". $identifiant ."') AND (`senha` = '". $senha ."')";
    $query = mysqli_query($sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 1) {
      // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
      echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
    } else {
      $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
      // Verifica se o usuário é 0 ou 1

      if ($resultado['ativo'] == 0)) { header("Location: principalUSU.php"); } 
      else { header("Location: principal.php"); }

      exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Para aprender mais sobre PHP e segurança de login, sugiro esse canal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCrf70u7hFI

Comment: Obrigada por responder! Eu copiei seu código, mas ainda dá o erro 500 quando cai na página de validação. Será que pode ser na página de login?

Answer (score 1):

Erro 500 é problema de programação, nesse caso você deve consultar o log do apache para ver as mensagens de erros ou habilitar a exibição dos mesmos apenas no script com as linhas, são colocadas no inicio.

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Como está usando as funções mysql_ antigas (que ja foram removidas do php7). O problema parece ser na conexão, não é possivel passar o nome do banco como quarto argumento o correto apenas paras as funções mysql_* é chamar `mysql_select_db()`

Mude:

```
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Para:

```
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 mysql_select_db('db_formacao');
```

Outro detalhe, tome cuidado com os operadores `&&` e `AND`, `||` e `OR` não são sinônimos.

**Relacionada:**

[Qual a diferença entre “&&” e “||” e “and” e “or” em PHP? Qual usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47886/91)

Comment: Obrigada por responder! Alterei a conexão como sugerido, mas ainda está dando o mesmo erro 500. é estranho que todas as respostas continuem dando o mesmo erro na página de validação. Será que pode ser na página do formulário o problema?

Comment: @MarianaFerreira mesmo com o `ini_set` não mostrou os erros? olhou o log do apache?

Comment: Ah, o erro era meu. Era um parêntese a mais. Desculpa.